# How to clean my my stove top?

Tags: cleaning

Just finished cooking up my first batch of home brew, and during the boil I boiled over just a little bit. Now there's this dark black burned stuff all over my stove that does not want to come off. Any ideas on cleaners to use?

Thanks!

Comment: What type of stove do you have? Is it a ceramic glass cooktop?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably caramelized sugars. It will dissolve in water, given enough time. If your stove top is a shape that will allow this, put some warm water on top of the stains, and leave it there four an hour or two, or even overnight. Otherwise, saturate a dish cloth with warm water and place it on top of the stain. Again, leave it for a few hours before scrubbing.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly stronger than normal PBW solution (or whatever cleanser you use for cleaning your brew equipment) will be all that's needed.  Plus some time and elbow grease.

Answer (score 0):

I used brillo pads and some elbow grease. Just be careful not to scrub too hard or you might remove some paint. This has worked an every stove I have. Using some hot water doesn't hurt either.